# Magento 2 - Edit Price/Quantity from Catalog > Products main view

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, catalog, stock

> Is it possible to edit information for products (such as the quantity
>   or price) on the overview page?

For instance, I have 15 products pulled up, and need to add stock to all of them (but different amounts). I was hoping you could do it without going into each item (by clicking edit) and entering it there. I hope that makes sense. If anyone is familiar with Solid Commerce or Collusion, that capability is there.
Attached is a screenshot of the page I am referring to. Would be amazing if there was a way to just edit the information for all items right there, click save and then be done without having to go into each one individually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go through the **[user manual of Magento 2](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/Resources/pdf/Magento_Open_Source_2.2_User_Guide.pdf)** in order to familiarize with the features available in product grid in the admin side.

The feature you are looking here is available by default in Magento 2.

In order to do this:

1. Select all the products of which you need to update the value by ticking the checkboxes.
2. From the `Actions` menu (which you can find at the top-left of the grid), select `Update attributes`.
3. Update the attribute value you want to update.
4. Perform save.

---

<sup>For more details, refer 182 page of user manual.</sup>

Comment: But you cannot give different values for the same attribute from product grid page. For that, you should definitely edit each individual product. Another solution which you can use here is Magento product import facility, where you can specify your inventory levels. You can refer products by their skus.